# Keep getting undefined for my req.body during login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In my express routes, I have a user signup and a user login. My user signup works fine, however my user login doesn't. I am always getting an undefined for my req.body inputs. I looked up it, and it keeps saying that I have to do `app.use('/', userRoute);` after I do the `bodyParser.json()` and `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })`, but it still doesn't work. Any guidance here would be appreciated as I have been trying to solve this for a few hours now and I am getting nowhere.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

//Body Parser
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use('/', require('./routes/userRoute'));

//DB Config
const db = process.env.MONGO_URI;

//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

userRoute.js

```
const Router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

Router.get('/api/login', (res, req) => {
    console.log('hit /api/login');
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Comment: Why is your login route a GET and not a POST?

Comment: Because I am using mongoose `Model.find()`, so it takes the body params and tries to find if they match in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

in `userRoute`, it is first `req` then `res`

```
const Router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

Router.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('hit /api/login');
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = Router;
```